# gnu make: How to concat two strings

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

Given the line:

```
program_OBJS := ${program_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
```

I would like to append `.o` to each filename instead of replacing `.cpp` with `.o`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To *just* append something to a list of space separated items you can use:

```
program_OBJS := $(foreach program,$(program_SRCS),$(program).o)
```

To use the substitution method (like you show in your question):

```
program_OBJS := $(program_SRCS:.cpp=.cpp.o)
```

but for that the list must contain the *.cpp* suffices, or the substitutions will not occur.

Comment: I thought `$(foreach)` literally expended the third argument and concatenated the results. I just tested it and it automatically adds a space if omitted, so it is not required. (I will remove the note from my answer and update my own Makefiles... ;) )

Answer (score 13):

How about this:

```
STRING1:="foo"
STRING2:="bar"

STRING1:=$(STRING1)$(STRING2)
```

Obviuosly, you could save the result to a new variable.

Comment: When I print the result of this I get "foo""bar" as the result of concatenation. How do I remove the unwanted quotes?

Comment: foo := "bar"
foo := $(patsubst "%",%,$(foo))

Answer (score 10):

GNU make has  [addsuffix](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/File-Name-Functions.html#index-addsuffix-591) function

Comment: +1 Does this work in other versions of make, or just gnu make?

Comment: @Robert: Just GNU make. If you want to stay portable with your Makefiles, the best bet is to write POSIX makefiles, as specified here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html

Answer (score 7):

Shorter alternative, using a pattern substitution: `program_OBJS := ${program_SRCS:%=%.o}`

Answer (score 3):

One more way working regardless of extension: `${program_SRCS:=.o}`

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess `program_OBJS := ${program_SRCS:.cpp=.cpp.o}`